# dart: get object within anonymous function

Tags: dart, anonymous-function, self-reference

I want to access the object itself within a listen-callback.

```dart
SomeObject o = new SomeObject()
    ..onEvent.listen((Event ev){

        //now I want to access Object o.

    });
```

It works if I call onEvent.listen after o is created, but I want to access it by the constructor, because some events are fired during construction. Is it somehow possible to access the object within this callback?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you try to do is recursive initialization.
You can do it like:

```dart
SomeObject o;
o = new SomeObject()
    ..onEvent.listen((Event ev){

        //now I want to access Object o.

    });
```

See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10751 for more details.